# Azure Data Factory and Calling an Azure Batch Job

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I am new to Azure Data Factory pipelines.

I want guidance on how to call an Azure Batch Job via a Azure Data Factory pipeline and monitor the batch job for failure/completion - is this possible ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I found the following articles which I am working through...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-data-processing-using-batch

Comment: Hi @Ian - just to be clear, those docs are for ADF V1. Hopefully you are using V2. Here is the appropriate documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity#executing-commands